# Space bar not working inside Atom text editor

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor

I have this issue with my space bar not working, especially inside the Atom text editor, but it works fine outside Atom.

For example, when I'm typing something inside Atom, every time I press the space bar, it comes back, or rolls back, to the same place where it was.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Any macros, plugins, scripts running in Atom?

Comment: Yes .I have installed many plugins to make development easier for me ?

Comment: Well, then the first suggestion is: disable all plugins. If the issue goes away it is a plugin interfering, so enable them one by one to find the culprit.

Comment: Actually, my problem is even worse, once I have Atom or Atom based editor installed such as VSCode, I cannot insert space in my Ubuntu shell, nor do in emacs buffer at all. But I can still insert space in web browser's input field (as I'm doing now here.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can rule out, that this is a global problem (your second paragraph makes me wonder), here are a couple of things you can try:

At first I'd run Atom in safe mode `atom --safe`, to make sure the problem is caused by a package. Safe mode starts Atom without loading any third-party packages or settings.

Next, I'd use the keybinding resolver to check whether the space-key is used by one of the packages. To do so, launch *Key Binding Resolver: Toggle* and press <kbd>Space</kbd>. If it's used by a package, it will be displayed in the bottom of the editor.

If none of this helps, you need to disable packages one by one to find the one causing the trouble.